# Undefined reference to `startswith'

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am writing some `C` in which the program is going to convert the first command line argument into a int and check to see if it is an int. If it isnt a integer value it will then attempt to check to see whether the string begins with a '.' character or not. For some reason I am getting an undefined reference. 
How is this an undefined reference when it seems to be defined?

Here is the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int startswith(char,char);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int forst;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int speed_delay = rand() % 20;
    printf("The speed delay is:%i\n", speed_delay);
    int first = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("First:%i\n", first);

    if (first == 0) {
        //this means text was inserted instead of a number
        if (startswith(first, '.')) {
            printf("string starts with a period !");

        }
    } else {

    }

    int startswith(const char * one,
        const char * two) {
        if (strncmp(one, two, strlen(two)) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: your function declaration doesn't match your definition. `(char, char)` is not the same as `(const char*, const char*)`. And `first` is an `int`, so you won't be able to pass that to either version.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.  Pay attention to them too.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration and definition of `startswith` are incompatible.

The declaration has two parameters of type `char`, but the function actually has two parameters of type `const char *`.

You also defined `startswith` *inside* of `main`.  Functions cannot be nested.

Because no function exists that matches the declaration, you have an undefined reference.

Fix your declaration to match the definition.

```
int startswith( const char *, const char *);
```

You're also not calling this function correctly.  You pass in an `int` and a `char`.  It should be called like this:

```
if(startswith(argv[1],"."))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try replacing int startswith(char,char); with below 

static inline const char *startwith(const char *s, const char *prefix)
{
    size_t sz = prefix ? strlen(prefix) : 0;
    if(s && sz && strncmp(s, prefix, sz) == 0){
        return s+sz;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```